# How to convert GEOJSON file to XYZ tiles

Tags: geojson, tiles, xyz

I have a shape defined in GEOJSON file. As it's quite huge, I would like to convert it to XYZ tiles. Is there a utility, which can create XYZ pyramid for me at once?

Comment: Raster or vector tiles?

Comment: Raster tiles. Sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use QGIS but Tilemill would be a good alternative.

Load your GeoJSON into QGIS and style it however you like it. Then use the QTiles plugin to render the raster tiles.